# Android studio jarsigner: key associated with key not a private key

Tags: android, android-studio

When am trying to generate signed bundle using android studio, am getting following error"

```
Cause: jarsignerfailed with exit code 1 :
jarsigner: key associated with india not a private key
```

- Tried to clean project, dint work.
- This issue was posted by another stack overflow post, but they recommended to clean an try agin, its not working for me

Note:
My keystore password and the other password is same. It used to work for me before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio Update bundle jarsigner: key associated with key0 not a private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54037262/android-studio-update-bundle-jarsigner-key-associated-with-key0-not-a-private-k)

Comment: yes, its duplicate, but i have also added a bounty to that question.

Comment: @user93796 Friend, did you get answer for this problem. Please help me too, i am also struggling to solve this issue since 3 days

Comment: @Dan did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply "india" is not an identifier of a private key, but a CN field in a certificate.
You need to list private keys using keytool, then use private key id instead of cert. name. in jarsigner.